# How can I round numeric area values in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, area, trigger

I am using a trigger function in PostGIS to calculate the area in hectare of each polygon that is created or changed. The field is called "flaeche_ha_gis", the datatype is "double".:

```
BEGIN
            NEW.flaeche_ha_gis = st_area(NEW.geom)/10000;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

It works fine, but the resulting area numbers have many decimals. How can I round the decimals to 2 digits ? I know I could use the function round(,2) but I don't know how to integrate it in the SQL statement.

Comment: I get this error message: PostGIS-Fehler beim Attributhinzufügen: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
    LINE 1: NEW.flaeche_ha_gis = round(st_area(NEW.geom)/10000,2)
                                 ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    QUERY:  NEW.flaeche_ha_gis = round(st_area(NEW.geom)/10000,2)
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function calculate_area() line 4 at assignment

Comment: The function round doest work with double precision but with numeric.
ST_Area output is double precision so you have to cast it to numeric before applying round.

round((st_area(new.geom)/10000)::numeric, 2)

Comment: Best use is to cast it back to double precision after that so :
round((st_area(new.geom)/10000)::numeric, 2)::double precision

Comment: the rounding of doubles has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13113096/7635569) quiet a bit

Comment: Leave it for the client to worry about?